# Postcode lookup with territories

Tags: geofinder

I wonder if anyone can point me in the right direction or even tell if there is something than can do the following.

Basically i want a postcode lookup that will return an entry based on territories/location so for example:

- I type my postcode in "LL28 4AU"
- Returns an entry that relates to that postcode
- if the postcode is not covered return a message saying sorry your area is not covered.

I dont want it to work from radius though because if there is an entry that is technically closer to the postcode but isnt actually covered by that entry and is actually covered one slightly further i would have a problem.

I need it to relate to terriroties / postcodes covered.

Sorry for badly worded question i cant find an easy way to say what i need.

Thankyou to anyone that can help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with UK postcodes which is going to make this difficult or at least costly to do "properly".

Unfortunately, and perhaps wrongly, the UK postcode data belongs to The Royal Mail. You can use it, but you have to but the data from them. Consequently there aren't any add-ons that can hook into this data to do what you want.

You may be able to get a list of postcode lat/lng details but I'm not sure how this would work since postcodes don't cover areas of similar size or shape.

I don't really understand the following:

> I dont want it to work from radius though because if there is an entry
>   that is technically closer to the postcode but isnt actually covered
>   by that entry and is actually covered one slightly further i would
>   have a problem.

Do you mean that you have a series of entries for, say, dealerships and each dealership covers specific postcodes? If so, then I think your best bet would be to make use of a simple text search.

Have a text field for each entry which contains the postcodes that it covers then run your search on that field to find a match. You may need to write a custom MySQL query and use the Query Module to execute it but from that point on it should be pretty straightforward to implement.

Comment: Hi thanks for response, 

Yes say LL20 - LL30 area covered by one dealer and then ll30 - onwards are covered by another. 

one dealer might have LL30 - ll50 but not have up to ll60 so if someone entered a ll52 postcode it would basically say sorry no one is dealing in your area. 

You suggested maybe a simple text search how would i go about doing this? As in making sure a particular entry of say "chester" covered ch1 - ch30?

If you know how to do this would you be able to do it for me or at least set it up for me to easily assign postcodes to entries? And how much would you want Cheers,

Wes

Comment: I'd make a plain text area field containing a comma delimited list of the relevant postcodes for each dealer. So for your example it might contain "LL20,LL21,LL22,LL23.... LL49,LL50". The MySQL query would be something like "SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname LIKE `%LL23%`". I'm afraid I can't do it for you as I'm currently fully booked out. But have a go and then ask more questions here. So long as the questions are nice and specific you should be able to work it out.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is it possible to use Expression Engine Search or even something like 'low search' and search the channel of 'franchises' in the text area field of "postcodes-covered" which is in every entry with the say "LL20,LL21,LL22,LL23.... LL49,LL50" and then limit the results to one? and instead of having a results page, just display the entry straight off?

Cheers.

Comment: Well if each postcode only exists in one franchise then it will only return 1 result. But yes, you can limit the results in the same way as you can limit entries shown from a channel entries tag pair. The key to this will be to use "Exact" search matching.

Comment: Thanks again, and is it possible to go straight to the entry as opposed to a results page first?

Comment: Just make your results page either display the entry in full or redirect to the URL for the template/entry you wish to display.

Comment: or use ``search_fields`` by croxton instead of search module